# Python не видит переменную table2

Tags: python, pandas

Код следующий:

```
import pandas as pd

sum_row1 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_1'].sum()
sum_row2 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_2'].sum()
sum_row3 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_3'].sum()
sum_row4 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_4'].sum()

table2 = pd.DataFrame( data= [[11,21,10, sum_row1], [10, 30, 20, sum_row2], [11, 41, 30, sum_row3], [50, -100, 30, sum_row4] ] , index = ['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4'], columns = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'sum'])

table2
```

Вывод:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\*USER*\Documents\hw7.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 3 sum_row1 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_1'].sum()
      4 sum_row2 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_2'].sum()
      5 sum_row3 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_3'].sum()

NameError: name 'table2' is not defined
```

Есть идеи?

Изменил:

```
import pandas as pd


table2 = pd.DataFrame( data= [[11,21,10, sum_row1], [10, 30, 20, sum_row2], [11, 41, 30, sum_row3], [50, -100, 30, sum_row4] ] , index = ['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4'], columns = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'sum'])

sum_row1 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_1'].sum()
sum_row2 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_2'].sum()
sum_row3 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_3'].sum()
sum_row4 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_4'].sum()


table2
```

Новый вывод:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\*USER*\Documents\hw7.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 3 table2 = pd.DataFrame( data= [[11,21,10, sum_row1], [10, 30, 20, sum_row2], [11, 41, 30, sum_row3], [50, -100, 30, sum_row4] ] , index = ['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4'], columns = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'sum'])
      5 sum_row1 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_1'].sum()
      6 sum_row2 = table2.loc['row_1', 'D'] = table2.loc['row_2'].sum()

NameError: name 'sum_row1' is not defined
```

Comment: есть идеи. Сравнить номера строк, где создается переменная, и где она используется.

Comment: Переменную нужно сначала присвоить, а потом использовать, а у вас наоборот. Сначала должно быть `table2 = ...`

Comment: Тогда почему код работал в таком виде до этого?

Comment: Предположу - это потому что вы работаете в `Jupyter Notebook` и он запоминает все переменные? А, ну да - `.ipynb`, ноутбук, ага.

Comment: нет, Visual Studio Code, переменные он не запоминает

Comment: Ну `VSC` тоже может в интерактивном питоне код выполнять, насколько я понимаю. Вы по ячейкам код выполняли до того или весь файл всегда? Ну в любом случае в таком виде код сам по себе работать не будет. А при выполнении по отдельным ячейкам переменные запоминаются, видимо `table2` была запомнена, а потом вы состояние сбросили.

Comment: Кажется, я видел уже на днях похожее задание... Запишите туда `None` пока при создании `DataFrame`. А дальше вы заполните эти ячейки в следующих строках кода. А, нет, просто выкиньте вообще пока колонку `D`, не создавайте вообще её и значения в ней.

Comment: Ну изменил, точно такая же ошибка. Ничего не напоминает?

Comment: "Тогда почему код работал в таком виде до этого?" - либо не в таком виде, либо не работал.

Comment: "Кажется, я видел уже на днях похожее задание... Запишите туда None пока при создании DataFrame. А дальше вы заполните эти ячейки в следующих строках кода. А, нет, просто выкиньте вообще пока колонку D, не создавайте вообще её и значения в ней" Можете написать как ответ?

Comment: А, и вообще я не понял при чём тут колонка `D`, вам же нужно колонку `sum` заполнять. Путаный код. Но ответ я добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно создать таблицу, а потом уже её заполнять. Столбец `sum` заполняется после, причём сразу во всех строках:

```py
import pandas as pd

table2 = pd.DataFrame(data= [[11,21,10], 
                             [10, 30, 20], 
                             [11, 41, 30], 
                             [50, -100, 30]],
                      index = ['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4'], 
                      columns = ['B', 'D', 'E'])

table2['sum'] = table2.sum(axis=1)
table2
```